PSQL 42501 insufficient privileges after GRANT command
I am currently trying to replicate a system from development to production. Both servers are running Postgresql 14, and Postgrest. I am attempting to update a row in the production system using my web app, which when I developed it worked flawlessly, but does not work in live.
I am sending a HTTP PATCH to the PostgREST api targeting my table rules using the following request,
curl https://production.server/psrest/rules?id=eq.2051989
-X 'PATCH'
-H 'authorization: Bearer'
--data-raw '{"extra_data":{"disableReason":"test"},"active":"False"}'


PostgREST treats the above as an UPDATE command when it hit's PSQL.
I am returned a 42501 from PSQL saying that there is insufficient privileges. I have replicated the same role level privileges on the dev and prod DB, so I am at a loss as to what is going on.
I issued a lookup for the privileges on the table here is the output of that (note I replicated dev which has a GRANT ALL on this table, but here is the output to prove i'm not going insane, I have truncated the default grantees). PostgREST runs as indicators_read in this specific example.
SELECT grantee, privilege_type 
FROM information_schema.role_table_grants 
WHERE table_name='rules';

    grantee     | privilege_type 
-----------------+----------------
 indicators_read | INSERT
 indicators_read | SELECT
 indicators_read | UPDATE
 indicators_read | DELETE
 indicators_read | TRUNCATE
 indicators_read | REFERENCES
 indicators_read | TRIGGER


Look at the PostgreSQL log and show us the log message and the statement that caused it.

Check if there's no RLS going on in the table in production too. And what's the exact error (the json output) PostgREST returns?

Sorry, I forgot to mention it's on RDS, so I can't get at the PSQL logs

{hint: null, details: null, code: "42501", message: "permission denied for table rules"} code :  "42501" details :  null hint :  null message :  "permission denied for table rules"

Are you sure there is no Row Level Security on the table? Also verify in the PostgREST logs if it's the correct role making the request (use log-level=warn to check it). It should look something like: 127.0.0.1 - <your_role> [<date>] ...

Yup certain as this works on no rows in the DB, also as said before, at the moment I can't get the PSQL logs as it's running on RDS remotely and I don't have access to the filesystem.

Regardless I have disabled Row Level Security on the table. Still encountering the same problem. I have no real idea what is causing the issue, as the log files only show there is a permissions problem, and a line showing the command executed.
